# Django - For a DecimalField with 4 decimal places how to only allow 2 decimal places in the form?

Tags: javascript, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

This is my first question on Stack Exchange so please let me know if I could write questions better in future.

I have a django project where the user edits a DecimalField form.
I have created a currency field in my models.py file as follows:

```
from django.db import models


class Transactions(models.Model):
    transaction = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19,decimal_places=4)
```

From reading online I've read that it's best to use 4 decimal places not 2 for currency.

When the user needs to edit the field in a form the field displays for example -589.0000, which is confusing for a currency input.

[<input type="number"> element for currency, too many decimal places](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAbH4.png)

I want only two decimal places to show in the input element ie -589.00 even better if the user can't input more than two decimal places.

This is how I am making the form in the views.py file, I added an onclick attribute testing if javascript could solve this issue, but this isn't working:

class TransactionsUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):

```
    model = Transactions
    # form_class = TransactionsUpdateForm
    fields = ['transaction']
    success_url = '/' # Trying to redirect user to the home page after creating a transaction
    def get_form(self):
        form = super().get_form()
        form.fields['transaction'].widget.attrs = {'onclick': 'commas(self)

        return form
```

template (html) also see the javascript function which isn't working currently...

```
{% extends "forecast/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load humanize %}
{% block content %}
{{ form.media }}
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Transaction</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <script>
               function commas(input){
                   input.value = Number(input.value).toLocaleString();}
            </script>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>


{% endblock content %}
```

I know that this is possible with javascript if it's <input type="text"> but I would prefer to keep as a number type as when on a phone the number keypad opens automatically. Also, I don't know how to change the input type from the default "number" to "text"